# Eclipse ERROR in loading the SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with eclipse that I can't run any emulator or any program that I had developed, after I open eclipse this error occurs

```
[2012-06-26 19:48:52 - Dex Loader] Failed to load C:\Users\Ahmed\android-sdk-windows\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar
```

Comment: android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools does that look right to u

Comment: It seams that your android sdk path is not correct.

go to Window > Preferences > Android it shows your Target(s) ??

Comment: just fix ur path once again and restart the eclipse it works fine

Comment: Hi  L7ColWinters
I,m not understand you

Comment: M Mohsin Naeem

I check the path more and more its correct

Comment: @Mohsin Naeem In my case, I verified the path and it looks correct. I am using "SDK Location: C:\Users\Jaime\android-sdks". My dx.jar file is specifically here: C:\Users\Jaime\android-sdks\build-tools\26.0.0-preview\lib\dx.jar. I still keep getting this error: "Dex Loader] Failed to load C:\Users\Jaime\android-sdks\build-tools\26.0.0-preview\lib\dx.jar".